# Emacs: Execute code in shell-script mode

Tags: emacs

In sh-mode in Emacs, I was looking for a way to execute a shell script in the current buffer directly like the C-c C-c in Python-mode.  Using M-! is really tiring.  Any amount of googling doesn't help.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`M-|` is `shell-command-on-region`

so if you want to execute the whole buffer, `C-x h M-|` or you can rebind to something more convenient.

Comment: Mmm... I get the prompt "**Shell command on region:**" in the mini-buffer.   How is this supposed to work? I thought the region selected was going to be executed in a shell...

Comment: @nephewtom just type `sh` in prompt and then contents of buffer will be run via shell

Comment: Thanks @tlegutko !

Answer (score 6):

When I am editing a shell script called foo.sh, I set the variable `compile-command` to "foo.sh".  Then, `C-c m` (compile) or `C-c r` (recompile) executes the script.  `C-c m` lets me add or modify arguments to the script before running it, `C-c r` will run it with the last arguments used.

Answer (score 1):

Rebind M-! to something you like better, you can do it to the local keymap to just affect the shell buffer.